# vue js v-model is doesn't change the value in the text input or the value in the data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, v-model

I am new to vue js
I am trying to use v-model with input field and returning data from the data function, but it doesn't work at all. this is the code:

```
<template>
  <h1>Heros</h1>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(hero, key) in heroes" :key="key">
      {{ key + 1 }} : {{ hero.name }}
    </li>
  </ul>
  <input v-model.trim="newHero" />
  <button :disabled="isDisabled">Add hero</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      newHero: "Aquaman",
      isDisabled: false,
      heroes: [{ name: "Batman" }, { name: "Superman" }, { name: "Wonder" }],
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

i have reviewed the docs and i think the syntax is correct as stated here: [link](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-bind)
I am using chrome Version 103.0.5060.134 (Official Build) (64-bit) on linux mint and I also tried firefox, it changed the data when I changed it from the Vue dev tools, but this didn't happen in chrome.

Comment: What issue you are facing ? For me code looks fine.

Comment: the value doesn't change when i input in the input field and even when changing it from the vue js dev tools doesn't work

Comment: It is updating. where you are checking updated value ? `v-model` always used for a two-way data binding. Can you please add your code how you are checking the updated `v-model` value ?

Comment: i know that but it doesn't do so for me at all. I am checking in the chrome vue js dev tools extension

Comment: Have a look in this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/uco7wL4t/. It is updating fine.

Comment: yeah! it works, but in the data() that value doesn't change and in a vue js tutorial [link]("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e-E0UB-YDRk&t=5653s"), the value is changing in the dev tools. but when i tried as you did and used the value inside the DOM it worked prefectly, thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246921/discussion-between-rohit-jindal-and-twfyq-bhyry).

Answer (score 0):

[https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html#text[enter](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html#text%5Benter) link description here][1]

```
<p>Message is: {{ message }}</p>
<input v-model="message" placeholder="edit me" />
```

Comment: it is the same as i did, but when using the value inside the dom only works. but the problem is still there in the chrome dev tools extension

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).